# Proof of measurability of a function.

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently reading through my notes and I have some trouble to understand this solution:

Let $(X, \mathbb X)$ be a general measurable space.

Then, as a partial exercise:

Let $(A, \mathbb A)$ be the measurable space where $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathbb A = \{X, \emptyset, \{2,3\}, \{1\}\}$. Show that $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is measurable iff $f(2) = f(3)$.

The solution goes like this:

First suppose that $f(2) = f(3)$. Let $c \in \mathbb R$. If $c < f(2)$ then $\{2,3\} \subset \{x : f(x) > c\}$ and we can deduce that $\{x: f(x) > c\} \in \{\{2,3\},X\}$ (Why is also $\{x : f(x) > c\} = X$ possible?). 
If $c \ge f(2)$ then $\{1\} \supset \{x : f(x) > c\}$ and we can deduce that $\{x : f(x) > c\} \in \{\{1\}, X\}$ (same question here).

But now they have shown that
\begin{align*}
c \in \mathbb R \Longrightarrow \{x: f(x) > c\} \in \mathbb A
\end{align*}
but the domain of $f$ is $X$ and not $A$? This confuses me.

Now suppose that $f$ is measurable and $f(2) > f(3)$ (the case $f(2) < f(3)$ can be handled similarly). Let $c \in (f(3), f(2))$. We then have that $2 \in \{x : f(x) > c\}$ but $3 \notin \{x : f(x) > c\}$. So $\{x : f(x) > c\} \in \{\{1,2\}, \{2\}\}$ which means $\{x : f(x) > c\} \notin \mathbb A$ and so $f$ is not measurable.
Can one do this direction in a direct way?

Thanks

Comment: Well, basically, let $f(2)=a$, then $f^{-1}(a)$ is not measurable if $3\notin f^{-1}(a)$ since neither $\{2\}$ nor $\{1,2\}$ is measurable. why need all this interval stuff?

Comment: Looks like for this question, A and X are supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

As Nate pointed out, $A$ and $X$ are the same thing here; inconsistency of notation.

You can make the second proof direct as follows: if $f$ is measurable, then $\{x\in A: f(x)=f(2)\}$ is  in $\mathbb A$  and contains $2$. But every element of $\mathbb A$ containing $2$ also contains $3$. Hence, $f(3)=f(2)$.

---

It may be more interesting to prove the following more general statement. Let $A$ be a finite set with algebra $\mathbb A$. Introduce equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$ as follows: $a\sim b$ if every measurable set containing $a$ also contains $b$. Then the following holds: a real-valued function on $A$ is measurable iff it is constant on every equivalence class.